# Retrieving primary key information with UCanAccess

Tags: java, jdbc, resultset, ucanaccess, database-metadata

I'm trying to get all database metadata from an Access database using the UCanAccess JDBC driver but I need to change my resultset type to navigate in the resultset but how to set the good type when my resultset are created with method from the interface databasemetadata ?
code here

```
 v_resultPrimaryKey = p_metadata.getPrimaryKeys(null, Tools.getDBName(), p_table);

        ResultSet v_resultColumn = p_metadata.getColumns(null, Tools.getDBName(), p_table, null);

        v_resultPrimaryKey.first();

        String v_pkName = v_resultPrimaryKey.getString("COLUMN_NAME");
```

Comment: You think you need to change the type why? What is the underlying problem?

Comment: when i wan't to use ".first" it says to me feature not supported

Comment: because the resultset with ucanacess is in forwardonly mode how can i change it

Comment: Why? Do you really need to go backwards? Why not just `next()` through it like everybody else?

Comment: one question if i do only one ".next" on a result set does it do the same effect as a ".first"?

Comment: Of course. You start before the beginning, then one `next()` gives you the first, another one the second, and so on. This is rather basic.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to change the ResultSet type in order to retrieve the primary key information. All you need to do is something like this ...

```java
try (Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(connUrl)) {
    try (ResultSet rs = conn.getMetaData().getPrimaryKeys(null, null, "InvoiceDetail")) {
        while (rs.next()) {
            System.out.printf("%s (%d)%n", 
                    rs.getString("COLUMN_NAME"), 
                    rs.getInt("KEY_SEQ"));
        }
    }
}
```

... which for a table like this ...

[image: InvoiceDetail.png]

... will produce output like this:

```
InvoiceNumber (1)
LineItemNumber (2)
```